# Should The First Kingdom be considered manga?

Tags: discussion

I just posted the following image to the auto-revived question, [What defines the art style of Japanese manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31114/what-defines-the-art-style-of-japanese-manga):

*Spoiler contains NSFW image*

> [image: The First Kingdom, book 6 cover]

I said that, except for his nationality, [Jack Katz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Katz_(artist)) might as well be considered a mangaka.  (Well, that and it took him 6 months between issues, not 1 (assuming 1 "book" equals 4 manga chapters).) My guess is that *The First Kingdom* would be off-topic for this site, however. Would it?  If so:

1. If a Japanese publisher translated it, erased all the nipples, and published it, would it become on-topic manga?
2. If an anime studio made it into an anime, would the source material be on topic?

(Due to the highly-detailed art style, I doubt #2 would ever occur. But hypothetically...)

Comment: Akira was wonderfully detailed, had nipples, and was still made into anime. And that was in 1988.

Comment: We have questions on here about what constitutes anime and manga, but none of them ever reach a definitive answer. We've basically decided on the arbitrary rule that if enough people think it should be on topic on an anime site, it's on topic, which is why Final Fantasy and Legend of Korra are on topic.

Answer (score 2):

I'll say what I believe definitively here:

## No.

If we start including more than Anime and Manga, even if the scope bends slightly, we're going to lose our focus.  In my mind, the art style doesn't matter; if we start to muddy our topic scope, we're going to get questions that Anime and Manga enthusiasts can't answer.